# Pandas - Operate on a column, filtered by another column in the dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with several columns with dates - formatted as datetime.

I am trying to get the min/max value of a date, based on another date column being NaN

For now, I am doing this in two separate steps:

```
temp_df = df[(df['date1'] == np.nan)]
max_date = max(temp_df['date2'])
temp_df = None
```

I get the result I want, but I am using an unnecesary temporary dataframe.

How can I do this without it?
Is there any reference material to read on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an MCVE that can be played with to obtain statistics from other columns where the value in one `isnull()` (NaN or NaT).  This can be done in a one-liner.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
print(pd.__version__)

# sample date columns
daterange1 = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2018-01-01', freq='MS')
daterange2 = pd.date_range('2017-04-01', '2017-07-01', freq='MS')
daterange3 = pd.date_range('2017-06-01', '2018-02-01', freq='MS')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'date1': daterange1})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'date2': daterange2})
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data={'date3': daterange3})
# jam them together, making NaT's in non-overlapping ranges
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=0, sort=False)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

max_date = df[(df['date1'].isnull())]['date2'].max()
print(max_date)
```